# How can I use command line to compile Hadoop source file

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

I recently successfully use the homebrew to install `Hadoop 2.6.0` on `Mac OS X 10.10.2`. But, Now. I have some trouble to compile the source file when I use `Command line`!

So I would like to know how to compile Hadoop program with the Hadoop 2.6.0 using command line. I am not really sure **which jar files I need to set as the classpath and how to set classpath**.

> Could you please help me, Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the dependencies used in the program. Basic hadoop-program require `hadoop-commons-version.jar` & `hadoop-core-version.jar`. 
Use the following

```
javac path-to/*.jar:path/to/*.jar classname.java
```